# Sorting and unsorting function

Tags: javascript, list, function, sorting

I made script for sorting (A to Z)

My question is what I need to add to this to have unsort function, I mean set to **default** (*how it was before you sort them*).

**Code:**

```
function sortList() {
  document.getElementById('sortedtxt').innerHTML = 'Sorted A-Z';
  document.getElementById('sortedtitle').innerHTML = 'BFMAS - Sorted A-Z';
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("sortingUL");
  switching = true;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this would be possible, except if you store somewhere the order before sorting.

Comment: just make a copy of the initial list

Comment: @johnSmith except that given how their implementing it here, it would be a copy of DOM elements... 

Comment: Before you sort set data-index on all the elements. You can then resort with those values.  Also odd you are not just using array.sort()

Comment: @Inigo i doubt that there will be any recognizable performance impact or whatever makes u  in fact its more inperformant to do dom-manipulation for each iteration than replacing / appending it once

Comment: @johnSmith that's exactly why i ... see the lead para of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Please use this code JS & HTML
>
> ```js
>   let globalList, temp = [], sorted = true;
>
>   document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener('click', sortList);
>   document.getElementById("unsorted").addEventListener('click', UnsortedList);
>
>   function UnsortedList() {
>     let currentList = document.getElementById("countries");
>     currentList.innerHTML = '';
>     temp.forEach(function (item) {
>       let li = document.createElement('li');
>       currentList.appendChild(li);
>       li.innerHTML += item;
>     });
>     sorted = true;
>   }
>
>   function getTempArray(pList) {
>     globalList = pList.getElementsByTagName("li");
>     temp = [];
>     for (let j = 0; j < globalList.length; j++) {
>       temp.push(globalList[j].innerText);
>     }
>   }
>
>   function sortList() {
>     let list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
>     list = document.getElementById("countries");
>
>     if (sorted === true) {
>       getTempArray(list);
>       sorted = false;
>     }
>
>     switching = true;
>
>     while (switching) {
>       switching = false;
>       b = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
>       for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
>         shouldSwitch = false;
>         if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
>           shouldSwitch = true;
>           break;
>         }
>       }
>       if (shouldSwitch) {
>         b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
>         switching = true;
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="es">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
>     <title>Pues </title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <p>Click the button to sort the list alphabetically </p>
> <button id="sort"><b>Sort</b></button>
> <button id="unsorted"><i>Unsorted</i></button>
>
> <ul id="countries">
>     <li>Peru</li>
>     <li>Argentina</li>
>     <li>Brazil</li>
>     <li>Colombia</li>
>     <li>Paraguay</li>
>     <li>Bolivia</li>
> </ul>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Run the code snippent 

Comment: Thank you, it's working :D

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems kind crazy that you are sorting DOM elements in situ (in place), rather than having a separate list data structure (e.g. an array) and treating the DOM as a view... i.e. rendering the list data into the DOM as needed (i.e. after it updates or after you sort it).

Recommendation:

1. Move the `sortedtxt` data into an array.
2. Keep a copy of the array for the original sort order.
3. create and call a function that renders the array elements into the DOM, e.g. into the appropriate `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<table>`.
4. On a user action that changes the sort order or restores the original, apply that to the array and then call the above function again.

Benefits:

1. Better webpage performance.
2. Cleaner, simpler that separates data from presentation code.
3. You can implement fancier sort features such as [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value) much easier.